# mysqld can't start without any info

Tags: mysqld

mysqld can't start without any info, that is the only information I get is 'Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!'.

I edited the my.cnf file to enable logging on /var/log/mysql/mysql.log but it apparently doesn't want to log anything.

So I don't know anything. I know there are many similar questions, but in most cases people are able to tell something more from the log file(s).

BTW, it is happening after abnormal system shutdown.

**Update 1**: in my.cnf file I can see a line like this:
*Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.*

When I open the file I can see this:
[mysqld_safe]
syslog

What does it mean? How can I see error log?

**Update 2**: when I do 
mysqlcheck -u root -p --all-databases

I get "Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) when trying to connect"

**Update 3**: OK, now I know what syslog is:) It says: Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: No space left on device
So now I have a final question - on which device?

Comment: Before making the recent changes, were you able to run the `MySQL service`?

Comment: Unless and untill, `MySQL` start, no command like `mysqld`, `mysqlcheck` will work.

Comment: Thanks, no I couldn't start it before. There was an abnormal system shutodwn, I coulnd't start the service even after a few machine restarts. Then I started digging in and then I reverted all my changes.

Comment: Do a df -h to see if any of your drives/partitions are full - if so, clear down some space. Failing that, I might suggest a reinstall of the server software?

Comment: Yes, I know this command, I just don't know where to look at. It tells me that the home directory has ~3.1GB of free space, so I believe it's enough? The only two dirs having low free space are / (/dev/sda1) - 15MB and /tmp (/dev/sda8) - 300MB - but how can I know which device does mysql talk about?

Comment: "...I know this command, I just don't know where to look at...": It seems your knowledge need to be improved ;-). BTW: if you cut/paste the output of "df -h" we can better drive you along the disk-cleaning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is there MySQL can not write to the directory you are pointing inside `my.cnf`, and it dose not have the right permissions. to fix this problem make sure the user MySQL has owner privileges on the directory that `my.cnf` is pointing for example lets say the `base_dir` is located under `/MySQL` , `data_dir` is located under `/MySQL/data` and the socket is located under `/tmp` in this example you need to make sure `/MySQL` and `/MySQL/data` are owned by MySQL user, for `/tmp` since its a default directory for Linux user MySQL should have read,write and execute privileges. also you need to make sure the partition that contain the `data_dir` is not full "contain enough free space"

Comment: Thanks, it appeared that I'm out of inodes, removing some temporary files solved the issue.